# Is there a php sendmail() function?

Tags: php, methods

I am trying to modify some php code and the previous coder has used a function  like

```
     if (!@sendMail($email, $subj, $msg, $site_email)
```

is there a function or method named sendMail() in php for mail functionality.

This is called inside a method which is a class method. Since this class does not inherit from any other class i'm guessing it's a php built in function.

But i  can't find anything on this when searching on google... i just find the normal mail() function.

Please advice.

Edit - Looks like i'll have to dig a bit more of code and see where it's defined. Anyone has any helpful hints for digging out  the function definitions  in a project that's basically spaghetti code.

And many thanks for all the help until now.

Comment: No, it's not a PHP built-in function.

Comment: See http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php

Comment: @Amit he wants to understand what the previous coder did there...

Comment: Sorry! English link: http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some one would have used that function in their own class or define it globally, but finally they have to call

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

So there is only mail function.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what it's calling, given what you've shown, code-wise, but that's almost identical to PHP's `mail()` function:

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

I highly doubt it's doing much different than just calling this function.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there's no such function in PHP, but if you want to send email using sendmail and PHP you can use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) class and set up the phphmailer object to use sendmail, see [this example](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/source/browse/branches/phpmailer-2.0/examples/test_sendmail.php) .

Comment: In most cases, PHP will already use sendmail since it's likely the default on the server. I don't think this function is specific to the "sendmail" package though, it's just a function that "sends mail".

Comment: Yap, ”in most cases” we don't know if the question is one of those cases or not.

Answer (score 2):

No. This is a custom-made PHP function. Only [`mail()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) exist. Try to stick with the pre-made ones *unless* you're actually doing something else (customizing it, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

You can always check if a function is available

```
<?php
if (function_exists('mail')) {
    echo "function is available.<br />\n";
} else {
    echo "function not available.<br />\n";
}
?>
```